# Is there a way to skip second level entity associations when fetching data into projections using JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Having entities structured in a tree with 3 levels I would like to fetch a list of projections of top level entity that include some properties of mid level entities, but skip fetching bottom level entities. I have a setup like one below:

```
@Entity
class TopLevelEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TopLevelEntityId id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mid_level_entity_id")
    private MidLevelEntity midLevelEntity;

    @Column(name = "some_number")
    private Integer someNumber;

}

@Entity
class MidLevelEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MidLevelEntityId id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "midLevelEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private BottomLevelEntityId bottomLevelEntityId;

}

@Entity
class BottomLevelEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BottomLevelEntityId id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mid_level_entity_id")
    private MidLevelEntityId midLevelEntityId;

}

interface TopLevelEntityProjection {

    TopLevelEntityId getTopLevelEntityId();

    @Value("#{target.midLevelEntity?.id}")
    MidLevelEntityId getMidLevelEntityId();

}

@Repository
public interface TopLevelEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TopLevelEntity, TopLevelEntityId> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"midLevelEntity.id"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    @Query("select e from TopLevelEntity e where e.someNumber > :someNumber")
    Page<TopLevelEntityProjection> findTopLevelEntitiesWithSomeNumberGreaterThanSomeOtherNumber(Integer someNumber, Pageable pageable);

}
```

First query that is being executed is fine -- it fetches top and mid level entities. However there is also a query for each of the bottom level entities -- they are lazily loaded even though they are not really used for anything. We could of course eagerly load bottom level entities to avoid multiple queries, but is there a way to skip those altogether?

**Edit:**

I can now see that this question can be simplified: same thing happens if I query MidLevelEntities directly. Despite projection not using BottomLevelEntities they are being lazily loaded anyway. At first I though that maybe that are accessed during some equals/hashCode call, but when I overriden the methods and setup a breakpoints in them, they were not called.

Comment: Are they lazily loaded during  `findTopLevelEntitiesWithSomeNumberGreaterThanSomeOtherNumber()` or at some point after that where you would need them?

Comment: During `findTopLevelEntitiesWithSomeNumberGreaterThanSomeOtherNumber()`. Here is an example trace: https://pasteboard.co/hXGDMfp8ZWBu.png (had to paint over it with data from the example, because production naming is diffrent)

Comment: Have you tried using `EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD`?

Comment: I did and it did't change anything, which makes sense, since fetch types on the relations are defined as lazy anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate ORM fetch a `@OneToOne` associations because it needs to know if the association is null or it needs to return an object (the proxy when the association is lazy). Using `FetchType.LAZY` doesn't change this behaviour.

I think there are three possible approaches to this:

- If you know that the association always exists, you can use `@JoinColumn(nullable=false)`. This way Hibernate ORM doesn't have to check and it will fetch the entity lazily
- Use a unidirectional one-to-one with `@MapsId`:

  ```
  @Entity
  class TopLevelEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TopLevelEntityId id;

    @Column(name = "some_number")
    private Integer someNumber;

  }



  @Entity
  class MidLevelEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MidLevelEntityId id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "top_level_entity_id")
    private TopLevelEntity topLevelEntity;
  }
  ```
- You can enable bytecode enhancements and use the annotation `@LazyToOne`

You can find more info for these use cases in the Hibernate ORM documentation:
[Bidirectional one-to-one lazy association](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional-lazy)

Comment: Thanks a lot! `@JoinColumn(nullable=false)` was not an option for us, but just a moment ago we managed to get it working with your last solution!