# Child Entity is also getting queried with Lazy loading in OneToOne Mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to lazily load a @OneToOne Mapped child Entity. I am using SpringDataJPA version-2.6.7

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public final class A {

  @Id private Integer id; 

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId
  @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private B b;
  
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public final class B {

  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "test_column")
  private String testColumn;
  
}
```

Here the Id of table 'A' and 'B' have shared primary key.

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {
  Optional<A> findById(Integer id);
}
```

When Invoking

```
 @Autowired
    ARepository repo;
    
    void fetchData(){
        repo.findById(1);
    }
```

Query to fetch both A and B is getting fired.
Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to skip second level entity associations when fetching data into projections using JPA and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72542732/is-there-a-way-to-skip-second-level-entity-associations-when-fetching-data-into)

Answer (score 0):

Try to also add `optional = false`:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
private B b;
```